# Capturar datos de formulario html y procesarlos en php

Tags: php, html

Buen dia, recien empiezo con el desarrollo web. Mi pregunta es: como puedo capturar los datos de un formulario html (es decir en el action del form) y procesarlos en un archivo externo php en el mismo directorio. Gracias, esto es lo que tengo:
DE HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">

    <h2>FORMULARIO DE ALUMNO:</h2>

    <div>
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name_user"/>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div>
        <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail" name="edad_user"/>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Enviar Informacion</button>
    </div>


</form>
```

EN PHP (file.php):

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad'];

    echo "Nombre: " + $nombre;
    echo "Edad: " + $edad;

?>
```

Comment: Para recoger los datos necesitas usar la propiedad `name`.  Ejemplo: `$nombre = $_POST['name_user'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `$_POST` recibe el valor del atributo `name` de tu `input`:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; //Incorrecto
$nombre = $_POST['name_user']; //Correcto, así lo tienes en tu html
```